# call to eval() blocked by csp error shows in couchdb _list

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

can anyone help me to enable the use of `Eval()` and `Function()` in couchdb design document.

I am trying to use `eval()` and Function methods in `_list` function but it always shows the below error when I call the list

> {
>       "code": 500,
>       "error": "render_error",
>       "reason": "function raised error: (new Error(\"call to eval() blocked by CSP\", \"lists.testing\", 1)) \nstacktrace: ([object Object],[object Object])@lists.testing:1\nrunList(function (head, req) {var

Comment: This sounds like a possible XY Problem. Why are you trying to eval code in a view function? What is it you're ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The eval function has been disabled by default in couchjs which is the process that evaluates the JavaScript functions defined in the design documents. You can see this change in this [commit](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/commit/1cd5852a758bf79c1860dae8d69e103d2e0611a4).

It seems that eval can produce some risks on the system as it can be used as a mechanism to run not controlled code in the server.

If you assume the risk, I suppose that you can reenable it by overriding the **[query_servers] javascript** config property in your *local.ini* config file. You need to add the *--eval* argument to the *couchjs* command.

```
[query_servers]
javascript = ./bin/couchjs --eval ./share/server/main.js
```